# how to override elementTmpl for billing address fields properly in checkout_index_index.xml?

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, billing-address, magento24

I would like to change the way the company field is rendered in the billing address and I'm trying to apply a new elementTmpl that I've defined and works well for shipping address fields.

Here's the XML

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/invoice-dependencies.js"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="vat_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="io_occupation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="io_tax_department" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                            </item>
                                        </item>

                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="billing-address-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                                             
                                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, I'm receiving an error just by inserting the new elementTmpl value even if I don't modify the original template.

```javascript
Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return element.hasAddons() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return element.elementTmpl }"
Message: Anonymous template defined, but no template content was provided
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:6092
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3730
    ignore /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1563
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3729
    arrayForEach /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:168
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3715
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3573
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToDescendants /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3789
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:4857
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2331
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2288
    evaluateImmediate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2253
    dependentObservable /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2085
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:4819
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3730
    ignore /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1563
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3729
    arrayForEach /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:168
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3715
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3573
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3576
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3576
    applyBindings /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3807
    _super /el_GR/mage/utils/wrapper.js:73
    applyBindings /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes.js:119
    wrap /el_GR/mage/utils/wrapper.js:78
    activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5870
    invokeForEachNodeInContinuousRange /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5821
    activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5868
    executeTemplate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5916
    renderTemplate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5962
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2331
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2288
    evaluateImmediate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2253
    evaluatePossiblyAsync /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2218
    notifySubscribers /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1401
    valueHasMutated /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1645
    observable /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1609
    makeTemplateSource /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine.js:197
    jQuery 7
    loadFromFile /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader.js:102
    execCb /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1650
    execCb /el_GR/mage/requirejs/resolver.js:156
    check /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:866
    enable /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1113
    bind /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:132
    emit /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1156
    each /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:57
    emit /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1155
    check /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:917
    enable /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1143
    init /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:774
    load /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:991
    bind /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:132
    loadContent /el_GR/mage/requirejs/text.js:155
    onreadystatechange /el_GR/mage/requirejs/text.js:122
knockout.js:6092:39
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:6092
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3730
    ignore /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1563
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3729
    arrayForEach /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:168
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3715
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3573
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToDescendants /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3789
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:4857
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2331
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2288
    evaluateImmediate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2253
    dependentObservable /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2085
    init /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:4819
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3730
    ignore /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1563
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3729
    arrayForEach /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:168
    applyBindingsToNodeInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3715
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3573
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3576
    applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3555
    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3576
    applyBindings /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3807
    _super /el_GR/mage/utils/wrapper.js:73
    applyBindings /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes.js:119
    wrap /el_GR/mage/utils/wrapper.js:78
    activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5870
    invokeForEachNodeInContinuousRange /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5821
    activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5868
    executeTemplate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5916
    renderTemplate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5962
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2331
    evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2288
    evaluateImmediate /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2253
    evaluatePossiblyAsync /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2218
    evaluatePossiblyAsync self-hosted:1178
    notifySubscribers /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1401
    valueHasMutated /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1645
    observable /el_GR/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1609
    makeTemplateSource /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine.js:197
    jQuery 7
    loadFromFile /el_GR/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader.js:102
    execCb /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1650
    execCb /el_GR/mage/requirejs/resolver.js:156
    check /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:866
    enable /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1113
    bind /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:132
    emit /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1156
    each /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:57
    emit /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1155
    check /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:917
    enable /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:1143
    init /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:774
    load /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:991
    bind /el_GR/requirejs/require.js:132
    loadContent /el_GR/mage/requirejs/text.js:155
    onreadystatechange /el_GR/mage/requirejs/text.js:122
    openPromptSync resource://gre/modules/Prompter.jsm:1057
    alert resource://gre/modules/Prompter.jsm:1329
```

Comment: It seems that when modifying via a LayoutProcessorInterface class, it will work correctly but it won't through the XML. I'm wondering why that difference. 

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit the content of the file, you need to copy the vendor file into your design theme.

Otherwise, if you want to change the template file (with a custom filename) you need to copy the xml file into your design theme (app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml) and change the elementTmpl with a valid path to your custom filename

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (using Plugin) for changing field order, disabling field or adding missing field to address.

File:

> etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Block_Checkout_LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="99"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
</type>
```

File:

> Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

https://pastebin.com/VxnyuCcg

Comment: Hi, I'm curious why XML instructions won't work, as noted above using a layout processor it actually works correctly. No need for a plugin either, just include the additional layout processor in the pool. But XML instructions won't work and cause abnormal behaviour

Comment: Maybe you changed something else with the core file. You can refer to this file of mine
https://pastebin.com/TLgbBtnz